# Trouble Opening File with FileProvider in Android 13 - "File not found" Error

Tags: android, uri, android-file, android-fileprovider, android-13

I'm encountering an issue when trying to open a file from the download folder using FileProvider in Android 13. The problem is that even though the file exists (confirmed with `file.exists()`), I'm getting a "Webpage not available. The webpage at content://com.telit.downloaddemo.fileprovider/document/Download/demo.txt could not be loaded because : net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error when attempting to open it with an HTML viewer application.

Below is the relevant code snippet:

```java
// Code in MainActivity.kt
private fun openFile(fileName: String) {
    val downloadPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path
    val filePath = "$downloadPath/$fileName"
    val file = File(filePath)

    if (file.exists()) {
        // Use FileProvider to get the content URI
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "com.telit.downloaddemo.fileprovider",
            file
        )

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        try {
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No app found to open the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.e(TAG, "openTextFile: ${e.message}", e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "openTextFile: ${e.message}", e)
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I've noticed that the URI obtained when using the Storage Access Framework (SAF) file picker is different from the one generated by my FileProvider implementation. The SAF URI looks like this: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000000076", while my FileProvider URI looks like this: "content://com.telit.downloaddemo.fileprovider/document/Download/demo.txt". The file is able to open in HTML Viewer application when using SAF.

I would like to open the file directly without using a file picker/SAF implementation. Any insights into why I might be encountering this issue or suggestions for a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not only use file.exists() but also file.canRead() before you use the file provider. If your app cannot read that file then fileprovider cannot let read other apps that file.

Comment: Yes those content schemes are different as it already starts with different provider/authority.

Comment: I think that file is not created by your app.

Comment: I already suggested why. The files are provided by a different provider. That's it. If my app would use FileProvider to serve a file the content scheme would differ from yours.